# get result in object form using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to call angular/ajax get the value from API and want setup my result in expecting results format. I try with my code but its calling twice times i don't know where i am mistaking please suggest

```
 $http.get('v1/res')
      .success(function (data) {

        $scope.results = [];

         angular.forEach(data.data, function(value, key){
            $scope.results.push({id: value.id});
            $scope.results.push({text: value.name});

         });

      });
```

//Expecting result

```
 $scope.results = [
    {id: 1, text: 'A'},
    {id: 2, text: 'B'},
    {id: 3, text: 'C'},
    {id: 4, text: 'D'},
    {id: 5, text: 'E'},
    {id: 6, text: 'F'},
    {id: 7, text: 'G'},
    {id: 8, text: 'H'},
  ];
```

Comment: What is the result that you are getting?

Comment: Maybe trying `$scope.results.push({'id': value.id, 'text': value.name});` ?

Comment: The way you are doing it now will push id and text as two different object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the result that you get from api call is the same object as you want then you can simply do as below

```
//assuming that data.data is an array of objects that you wish for
$scope.result = []
angular.copy(data.data, $scope.result)
```

otherwise

```
$scope.result = []
data.forEach(function(d){
    $scope.result.push({"id":d.id, "text":d.text});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it enough for you getting the data you want from `data.data`, since it's an object with the value you want.

As you wish getting the expecting format, it should be `object` with `id` and `text` as its properties stored in `$scope.results`, but in your code, they are being stored respectively as individual object with one property. So you code should be changed like this:

```
angular.forEach(data.data, function(value, key){
    $scope.results.push({id: value.id, text: value.name});
});
```

`{id: value.id, text: value.name}` is the object you want to be stored in your `$scope.results` I think.